# AfterOpen TcxDBcurrencyEdit

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I 'm using Delphi 7.
I want to use TcxdbcurrencyEdit instead of using TDBEdit, but the probleme I didn't find the AfterOpen events when affecting my datasource to my component.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TDBEdit` does not have events like `AfterOpen`, `AfterCancel`, `OnNewRecord` - they are all events of a `TDataSet`, not a `TDBEdit`.  So, if you want to access those you need to select your dataset in the `Object Inspector`, then click its `Events` tab.

Now that you've added some more explanation in your "answer", I follow what you're saying.  In the `Object Inspector`, on the `Events` tab for a `DBEdit`,  above `OnChange`, `OnClick` etc, there is a red label `DataSource` and if you expand it you can see a label `DataSet` and, if you expand that, you can see its events.

Where your confusion is arising is that I think you've missed the point that what the Object Inspector is showing you is just the `DataSource` connected to the `TDBEdit` (via its `DataSource` property on the OI's `Properties` tab) and the `DataSet` to which the `DataSource`'s `DataSet` property is set.  These `DataSource` and `DataSet` objects are the ones on your form (or datamodule if you're using one), and the red `DataSource` label of the `DBEdit`'s Events tab is just a quick way of showing you relevant properties of them.  If you want to inspect them in full, you just click them on the form as usual to select them for the `Object Inspector`.  So, to see the `DataSet`'s Event, just click it on your form and then click its `Events` tab in the `Object Inspector`.  It's that simple!

Its true that there is no similar red `DataSource` label for a `TcxCurrencyEdit`, but that's just because its developers have chosen to omit that from what the `Object Inspector` shows - it does **not** mean that associated `DataSource` + `DataSet` and its events are missing.

<s>[Original]</s>

<s>Assuming you have a `TDataSet` and a `TDataSource` on your form, to add a `TcxDBCurrencyEdit` all you need do is to drop one on your form, then, in the `Object Inspector`, click on the '+' sign next to its `DataBinding` property to expand it, then set its `DataSource` property to your `DataSource` and its `DataField` property to the name of your currency field.</s>

Comment: yes that's why I did, I add my Datasource and Datafield , but as I said I want to replace my component TDBEdit by using TcxdbcurrencyEdit , I add the datasource and the datafield.  But comparing to my TDBEdit in the events there are many events like After open , Aftercancel , on new record .... but when I click in the events of inspector object of my componnent TcxDBcurrency i didn't found them ?

Comment: I think you may be confused.  A TDBEdit does **not** have events like AfterOpen, AfterCancel, OnNewRecord - they are all events of a TDataSet, **not** a TDBEdit.

Comment: Yes I m confused but why I can't find this events in the events of tcxDBcurrencyEdit like TDBEdIT

Comment: Well, if you think you can see those events in a TDBEdit despite what I said about it not having them, I suggest you take a screen-shot of where you can see them with a TDBEdit and post it into your question so we can see exactly what you mean.

Comment: I can't add a picture I have alwyas this message "Request returned an error: [error] Forbidden" So I try to explain when I use a DBEDIT component there in the events the Datatsource and when I click in the '+' next to the Datasource , I have also the Dataset , when I click in '+' next to the Dataset there are some events like AfterCancel, AfterClose ..... AfterOpen ... But when using the TcxDBCURRENCYEDit , I didn't find the datatsource and the events linked to it

Comment: There are some example using TcxDBcurrencyEdit with dataset please.

Comment: What kind of example do you need?  Anyway, you should ask this as a new, separate q, not in an "answer" to this q.  There is no provision on SO for people to answer a question posed in an answer.